# Trying move my Wordpress website hosted using Nginx and Bitnami to a different url path but the CSS and JS files become unavailable

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

So I tried changing the site-url and home in wp-config.php from

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

to

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog');
```

The website opens just fine, but the CSS and JS files are now getting picked up from

```
'wp.domain.com/blog/wp-content/....'
```

instead of

```
'wp.domain.com/wp-content/...'
```

and so the CSS and JS files are unavailable. I also tried doing the wp-options update but couldn't change anything.

Is there a solution or am I following the wrong process maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: So the website is still located at `/`, you haven't actually moved the website. If you just want the permalinks to begin `/blog`, you can create a custom path in the settings menu on the dashboard. IDK, but those two variables have different functions, you may have success by setting one to `/` and the other to `/blog/`.

Comment: Have you done a search-replace in the database? Have your flushed Permalinks? Do you have any caching plugin that could be loading old files?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here, please follow these steps to move the app to /blog

- Log in to the server console using SSH.
- Edit the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/nginx-prefix.conf file and update it to reflect the new path:

  ```
  location /blog {
    alias "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs";
    include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/nginx-app.conf"; 
  }
  ```
- Look for the lines below in the file /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php file:

  ```
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
  define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
  ```
- Modify them to reflect the new path, as below:

  ```
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog');
  define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog');
  ```
- Restart NGINX:

  ```
  sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart nginx
  ```

You can find more information in our documentation:

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress-pro/administration/use-url-subpath/

Comment: Thanks a ton! But what worked fro me was not changing the siteurl and only the home url.